# Add or minus a variable value on button click?

Tags: javascript, variables, buttonclick

I'm very new to javascript so please forgive me this if it's actually a crazy simple thing to do, but I've been googling and going through all my reference sites with no luck.  What I'm trying to do is display a variable's value and change the value the variable either +1 or -1 when the user clicks the appropriate button - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaFz9.png).

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: this isn't about googling or reference sites. It's about having a basic understanding of the language. If you can't figure out how to do this task then you're simply not ready to use this tool. If you don't know what nails do, or what wood does, then asking "how do I use this hammer" is a fairly pointless question.  At the very least show us what you've tried and we can help you correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example you can work with. It's a full HTML page, which you can open in a web-browser to see in action. Copy and paste it into a text-file, which you save as `example.html`. Open it in notepad or something similar to edit it.

This is just one simple example - there are many ways to do stuff like this. Google around, see examples, and play around with them, and it will make sense, bit by bit.

Though it is old, and not always perfect, [the examples at W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) may still be a good place to start if you want to know more.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentValue = 0;
        var add = function(valueToAdd){
            alert("adding: " + valueToAdd);
            currentValue += valueToAdd;
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;
        };
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="text">Number of eggs:<span id="number">0</span><div>
        <a href="javascript:add(1)">Plus 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:add(-1)">Minus 1</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: One little addition: If you want a fairly new and good book on Javascript, and want to learn it "correctly", then [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) is probably the book you want. It is not a big book (just under 100 pages if I remember correctly), but gives a nice overview of the language.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been looking for! And yes, W3C is my main reference site, lol. I'm afraid my javascript books are out of date as well. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure! I updated the post and added a link to "the" java script book to start with if you want to get serious about the language. Good luck! :)